# Regular Expression (preg_match_all)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a private website where I share videos (and some other stuff).
What I have achieved is that with `preg_match_all()` it automatically finds the link and it paste the video with the HTML code to my website.

Here an example:

```
    <?php
$matchwith = "http://videosite.com/id1 http://videosite.com/id2 http://videosite.com/id3";
preg_match_all('/videosite\.com\/(\w+)/i', $matchwith, $matches);  
foreach($matches[1] as $value)
{  
  print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$value.'">Hyperlink</a>';           
}      
    ?>
```

This works. I know this could may could be done easier, but it has to be this way.

But I do not know how this with a two part movie. Here an example:

```
    $matchWith = "http://videosite.com/id1_movie1 http://videosite.com/id2_movie1"
               "http://videosite.com/id3_movie2 http://videosite.com/id4_movie2";
```

Everything after http://videosite.com/(...) is unique.

What I want is if you write Part 1 and Part 2 (or whatever) before the link, that it automatically detects it as Part 1 and Part 2 of this video.

$matchwith could contain different movies.

Comment: As I understand - you want group movies by their parts?

Comment: And id will be same for all parts?

Comment: No, ID will be differently for every Part. For example like youtube: Every video has its own id.

Comment: Something must be similar to identify parts for same movie. I thought that it will be possible to do by analyzing ids, but you say that they will be different for all all parts...

Comment: If I write something  before the link like Part 1 = The Link Part = The Link. How could this work?

Comment: Can groups be separated with line break? So each link will be in own line.

Comment: You mean each group will be in own line? Yes this could be possible. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe this is what you need:

```
<?php
$matchWith = "Movie 1 http://videosite.com/id1" . PHP_EOL .
         "Movie 1 http://videosite.com/id2" . PHP_EOL .
         "Movie 2 http://videosite.com/id3";

$arrLinks = array();
preg_match_all('%(.*)\shttp://videosite\.com/(\w+)\r{0,1}%', $matchWith, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
for ($matchi = 0; $matchi < count($result); $matchi++) {
    $arrLinks[$result[$matchi][1]][] = $result[$matchi][2];
}

foreach ($arrLinks as $movieName => $arrMovieIds) {
    print '<div>' . $movieName . '</div>';
    foreach ($arrMovieIds as $movieId) {
        print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$movieId.'">Hyperlink</a><br/>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are welcome :) As I understand stackoverflow is a place where help will be provided when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$matchwith = "Part 1 http://videosite.com/id1-1 Part2 http://videosite.com/id1-2";
preg_match_all('/videosite\.com\/(\w+-\d+)/i', $matchwith, $matches);  
foreach($matches[1] as $value)
{  
  print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$value.'">Hyperlink</a>';           
}
```

Comment: I had to correct your regex. I assume it was using the incorrect url. Perhaps not?

Comment: You are right but I am still waiting for an answer. I just need it for two parts movies. Thanks.

Comment: @Helena sorry, I have updated my answer :). The output I get is: <a href="http://videosite.com/id1-1">Hyperlink</a> <a href="http://videosite.com/id1-2">Hyperlink</a>

Comment: @Moz Morris - ids will be unique for each part :) i.e. can be xxx and yyy

Comment: Yes. Ids will be unique for each Part. Can it somehow be done this way? Movie1: Part 1 = The Link 1 Part 2 = The Link 2 Movie2: Part 1 = The Link 1 Part 2 = The Link 2? Thank you so much.

Comment: Also important: $matchwith could contain different movies. Sorry forgot to mention. But I think this is really important